# Jarsigner duplicate entry error while signing Corda workflows jar

Tags: java, corda, jarsigner, jar-signing, cordite

I try to sign my Corda workflows jar for which I do the following command:
`jarsigner -keystore test_app_sign.jks -storepass password123 -keypass password123 tcw-workflows.jar test_app_alias`

but I get this error:
`jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties`

When I run the following command agains my jar `jar tf workflows.jar | grep META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties` I can see 5 `META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties` files inside.

And when I run the following command to see the contents of those files

`unzip -p tcw-workflows.jar META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties`

I see the following:

```
#Generated by netty-parent/pom.xml
#Fri, 08 Mar 2019 10:44:41 +0000

netty-resolver-dns.version=4.1.34.Final
netty-resolver-dns.buildDate=2019-03-08 10\:44\:41 +0000
netty-resolver-dns.commitDate=2019-03-08 08\:51\:34 +0000
netty-resolver-dns.shortCommitHash=ff7a9fa
netty-resolver-dns.longCommitHash=ff7a9fa091a8bf2e10020f83fc4df1c44098bbbb
netty-resolver-dns.repoStatus=clean
#Generated by netty-parent/pom.xml
#Fri, 08 Mar 2019 10:31:53 +0000

netty-codec-dns.version=4.1.34.Final
netty-codec-dns.buildDate=2019-03-08 10\:31\:53 +0000
netty-codec-dns.commitDate=2019-03-08 08\:51\:34 +0000
netty-codec-dns.shortCommitHash=ff7a9fa
netty-codec-dns.longCommitHash=ff7a9fa091a8bf2e10020f83fc4df1c44098bbbb
netty-codec-dns.repoStatus=clean
#Generated by netty-parent/pom.xml
#Fri, 08 Mar 2019 10:38:05 +0000

netty-codec-http2.version=4.1.34.Final
netty-codec-http2.buildDate=2019-03-08 10\:38\:05 +0000
netty-codec-http2.commitDate=2019-03-08 08\:51\:34 +0000
netty-codec-http2.shortCommitHash=ff7a9fa
netty-codec-http2.longCommitHash=ff7a9fa091a8bf2e10020f83fc4df1c44098bbbb
netty-codec-http2.repoStatus=clean
#Generated by netty-parent/pom.xml
#Fri, 08 Mar 2019 10:43:07 +0000

netty-handler-proxy.version=4.1.34.Final
netty-handler-proxy.buildDate=2019-03-08 10\:43\:07 +0000
netty-handler-proxy.commitDate=2019-03-08 08\:51\:34 +0000
netty-handler-proxy.shortCommitHash=ff7a9fa
netty-handler-proxy.longCommitHash=ff7a9fa091a8bf2e10020f83fc4df1c44098bbbb
netty-handler-proxy.repoStatus=clean
#Generated by netty-parent/pom.xml
#Fri, 08 Mar 2019 10:41:37 +0000

netty-codec-socks.version=4.1.34.Final
netty-codec-socks.buildDate=2019-03-08 10\:41\:37 +0000
netty-codec-socks.commitDate=2019-03-08 08\:51\:34 +0000
netty-codec-socks.shortCommitHash=ff7a9fa
netty-codec-socks.longCommitHash=ff7a9fa091a8bf2e10020f83fc4df1c44098bbbb
netty-codec-socks.repoStatus=clean
```

So these are different files and I guess they all need to be there but the fact that all of them has the same name prevents jar signer to sign the jar. Is there any ideas how can this be solved?

P.S. my workflows project has a dependency `io.bluebank.braid:braid-corda:4.1.1` which I guess has dependency to `netty`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
    exclude '**/io.netty.versions.properties'
}
```